# Have any of the child actors from Stargate (1994) spoken about their hair and makeup?

Tags: stargate-1994

Stargate (1994) was a great movie and I'd love to learn more about what went into making it. In particular I wanted to find any interviews with the children.

I'm especially interested in learning about hair and makeup involved in the film, for example whether their hair was cut or if they wore headpieces.

[image]

Comment: are you asking about their hair cut or about the interview?

Comment: @JM - I've removed the chatter. It looks as if he's interested in the question of their hair and makeup.

Comment: I distinctly remember an interview/showcase on Jaye Davidson back in the day behind the scenes on the Stargate set as Hollywood was calling him the new up and comer and then he just completely dropped out of showbusiness.  I believe it was Entertainment Tonight.  Can't seem to find it, though

Comment: @steelersquirrel - Apparently he hated acting, disliked the media tour that they made him do after Stargate and retired after having made just two films; https://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/whatever-happened-crying-game-star-jaye-davidson-170059488.html?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly9lbi53aWtpcGVkaWEub3JnLw&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAEbowSHRNiuvlqNvZJd-1Q9xcw3fc7IyoGgdJxClDbfQB7uJoc7SkJOKodvIbUg145LPE6bm3jxVc_2uzCaDGwXl7BqYxTjEWng0NId9qzJNL3M5BMkTd7611iKqGx6Y95qklNfmKlgUWCeSB6z71S2dDIWRjZj96a1bOsq2pvrX

Comment: @Valorum Yeah.  I remember reading that about him.  Too bad as he did a terrific job in The Crying Game and Stargate

Comment: Reminds me of a bunch of soldiers who had a film night and someone recommended crying game. Different times, different bruises...

Comment: Looking at the cast list for Stargate, the children appear to be uncredited extras, so there is unlikely to be interviews held with such unimportant members (compared to the main cast). As for costumes, you might be lucky to see the crowd costume crew at work, but rarely an interview. It is unlikely that you will find what you are looking for. You mentioned Apocalypto children being interviewed but I think this is because they were more important characters than the ones in Stargate.

Comment: BTW, if they were foreground they might have haircut/alterations, if they were background they were probably just pieces stuck over hair. Extras more willing or capable of major changes would be more in the foreground or even featured, yet still would be uncredited - they just get paid more, for being more flexible with production.

Comment: Asking us to find interviews for you is off-topic here, and your question might get closed as an off-topic ID question. Please [edit] your question and the title to ask directly about what you want to know.

Comment: @galacticninja I'm not understanding how this is an ID question

Comment: @steelersquirrel It *is* an ID question, that's why I asked OP to revise their question.

Comment: @galacticninja How is it an ID question?  It's not asking to identify a movie or TV show.  No reason that this should have close votes on it, either.  But...okay.

Comment: @steelersquirrel It asks users to *identify* an interview fitting the OP's requirements. If this is an incorrect interpretation, I encourage you or the OP to [edit] the question and clarify accordingly.

Comment: @galacticninja OP is asking for interviews/information about the making of the film.  They are not asking for a _specific_ interview.  They are looking for _any_ interview/information about the subject

Comment: @steelersquirrel Just to clarify, I posted my original comment (that you replied to) before the question was edited to its current revision. My reply to you above was also based on the previous revision of the question. The current title is better, but the question body still asks for interviews that match the OP’s (IMO) vague and broad criteria, so I see why it’s still getting close votes. It should be rephrased to be more specific and clear about what the OP wants to know in particular, rather than asking users to find interviews.

Comment: @galacticninja That's fine and I understand when you posted your original comment.  If you wanted to put a close vote on it, that's your right; however, it shouldn't be a close vote for being an ID question.